# Cannot import maven project in eclipse due to error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I tried to import a java maven project in my computer, into eclipse sts/spring tool suite 3.9 as follows: eclipse sts > file menu > import > existing maven projects > etc.

I got an error message box with the following message:
An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
Path for project must have only one segment.

I could not find any answers on google to fix this problem. How do I fix this error ?

Comment: Does _File > Open Projects from File System..._ work?

Comment: @howlger - thanks. I discovered that and was posting my own answer here.  you beat me to it :)

Comment: Why the negative score on this?

Answer (score 10):

The problem was fixed by importing the project in a different way as follows:

eclipse sts > file menu > open projects from file system > import source = the root directory of the project (eclipse automatically detects this as a maven project) > finish.

Comment: I think this is a good answer.  Helped me.  Mark it as the solution.

Comment: This helped me a lot.

Comment: But why doesn't import -> maven -> existing maven project work? What is the difference?